# How to reference android navigation up icon within Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-navigation

I have been searching the reference to the navigation up icon for android within android studio but cant find it.  I am trying to add it to a toolbar. The toolbar is not the action bar.  I have a toolbar in a sliding up panel. The picture below is the icon I am looking to reference without adding:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

If it can't be referenced as a drawable I am assuming I will need to import images which I am trying not to do. If that is the case then please provide a page that has the exact icon as a .png.

If you are going to down vote the question provide an explanation on why.

[image: Android L Up Navigation Icon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting the Material Icons from Google's GitHub

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons

Answer (score 1):

actionbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);

Hope this helps

Comment: If you could some explanation why this should help, and a bit of code formating would be great. :)